# MySQL where clause Not functioning

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to rank certain records based on two where clause.

here is the Query: (without where clause which is working)

```
SELECT *, FIND_IN_SET( `trophies`, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `trophies` ORDER BY `trophies` DESC ) FROM player_profile ) ) AS rank FROM player_profile
```

But when any one of these where clause is introduced no rows returns.

```
SELECT *, FIND_IN_SET( `trophies`, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `trophies` ORDER BY `trophies` DESC ) FROM player_profile ) ) AS rank FROM player_profile WHERE plyID='4578911' AND category='First (TH10-TH11)'
```

i need help to rank based on 'trophies' with category and plyID.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure there are records which meet that criteria? Could you please provide more information regarding your schema. Also would be worth trying SELECT *, FIND_IN_SET( 
 `trophies`, (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( 
   `trophies` ORDER BY `trophies` DESC 
  ) 
 FROM player_profile 
 WHERE plyID='$playerID' AND category='$category'
 ) 
) AS rank FROM player_profile

Comment: Yes the criteria met the records in the DB. what more information you want, please specify. Also nope not working. And down voting won't help anyone.

Comment: @AccountUnknown can you see if there's anything from using error reporting and checking for errors on the query? I don't know which API you're using to connect/query with, so I don't know which link to give you to check for it. Provide a db schema with example values also. This will help (and hopefully expedite) a probable solution for you. Make sure those variables have values also.

Comment: I would expect the where clause to appear in the subquery

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I have made changes as per your request, hope this satisfies.

Comment: @AccountUnknown Thanks. However, my comment was a multi-part one ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can sort these records based on the trophies count, but it cannot retrieve the only records i need, which is plyID and category.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't understand can you help please? stuck at this for hours...

Comment: `WHERE plyID='4578911'` your `plyID` column's row doesn't have that number, `gametag` does. @AccountUnknown

Comment: @AccountUnknown *"can you help please?"* - and I have tried; where are we with this? Didn't get any feedback from my last comment.